# numbering duplicated rows in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I come to an issue with numbering the duplicated rows in data.frame and could not find a similar post.

Let's say we have a data like this

```
df <- data.frame(gr=gl(7,2),x=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","a","a","c","c","d","d","a","a"))


    > df
   gr x
1   1 a
2   1 a
3   2 b
4   2 b
5   3 c
6   3 c
7   4 a
8   4 a
9   5 c
10  5 c
11  6 d
12  6 d
13  7 a
14  7 a
```

and want to add new column called `x_dupl` to show that first occurrence of `x` values is numbered as `1` and second time `2` and third time `3` and so on..

thanks in advance!

The expected output

```
 > df
           gr x x_dupl 
        1   1 a  1
        2   1 a  1
        3   2 b  1
        4   2 b  1
        5   3 c  1
        6   3 c  1
        7   4 a  2
        8   4 a  2
        9   5 c  2
        10  5 c  2
        11  6 d  1
        12  6 d  1
        13  7 a  3 
        14  7 a  3
```

Comment: @RonakShah So sorry. I just realized it. Please see the updated OP.

Comment: More rows in your expected output than input?

Comment: @neilfws Sorry. I also forgot to change it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example data (plus rows where `gr = 7` as in your output), and named `df1`, not `df`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(gr = gl(7,2),
                  x  = c("a","a","b","b","c","c","a","a","c","c","d","d","a","a"))

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(x_dupl = dense_rank(gr)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 14 x 3
       gr      x x_dupl
   <fctr> <fctr>  <int>
 1      1      a      1
 2      1      a      1
 3      2      b      1
 4      2      b      1
 5      3      c      1
 6      3      c      1
 7      4      a      2
 8      4      a      2
 9      5      c      2
10      5      c      2
11      6      d      1
12      6      d      1
13      7      a      3
14      7      a      3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(gr=gl(7,2),x=c("a","a","b","b","c","c","a","a","c","c","d","d","a","a"))

x <- rle(as.numeric(df$x))
x$values <- ave(x$values, x$values, FUN = seq_along)
df$x_dupl <- inverse.rle(x)
#    gr x x_dupl
# 1   1 a      1
# 2   1 a      1
# 3   2 b      1
# 4   2 b      1
# 5   3 c      1
# 6   3 c      1
# 7   4 a      2
# 8   4 a      2
# 9   5 c      2
# 10  5 c      2
# 11  6 d      1
# 12  6 d      1
# 13  7 a      3
# 14  7 a      3
```